# which one overrides other? httpruntime executionTimeout or Connection Time-out

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

As per subject which one overrides other?

executionTimeout in web.config or Connection Time-out property in iis7 website properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the connection times out, it could be caught and a response still served. If the executionTimeout is hit, it has to be handled differently(most likely in the Application_Error method). If neither are handled, both would cause a bad response.

Comment: thanks, on upload wich one would timeout for large files? my guess is execution

Comment: Most likely. You could make sure that happens by allowing the upload and then storing in a different process/thread to speed up the response. Or see if you can change the executionTimeout value for that specific request.