# What is the difference between web.config executionTimeout and IIS timeout?

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, web-config, windows-server-2008

What is the difference between the following entry in web.config:

```
 <httpRuntime ... executionTimeout="1300" ... />
```

And this setting in IIS 7.5 (Default web site > Advanced Settings > Connection Limits) :

[image]

It seems executionTimeout is not the same as IIS timeout. What is the difference?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582102/which-one-overrides-other-httpruntime-executiontimeout-or-connection-time-out check this. Hope it helps

Answer (score 7):

`connectionTimeout` applies to the TCP connection between client and server, while `executionTimeout` applies to an actual web request that is sent over that connection.

From [here](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/sitedefaults/limits#005) on `connectionTimeout`:

> Specifies the time (in seconds) that IIS waits before it disconnects a connection that is considered inactive.

From [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#Anchor_0) on `executionTimeout`:

> Specifies the maximum number of seconds that a request is allowed to execute before being automatically shut down by ASP.NET.